# Find directory names with N occurences of a set of characters

Tags: find, regular-expression, directory, ls

**How to match non-recursively directory names that contain N occurrences of a subset of characters (using `find`)?**

In my specific case, I just want directory names with 6 digits. Here is what worked but is non-specific (it will give me all directory names with digits):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex './[0-9]+'
ls -d +([0-9])
```

This worked too, but gave me names of directories beginning with numbers and followed by anything:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '[0-9]*'
```

From what I read, I don't know how to make `ls` match N occurrences because it uses globs and not regular expressions (and I know nothing about globs). And what I can't understand  is that non of these worked using `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex './[0-9]{6}'
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '[0-9]{6}'
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '[0-9]+'
```

I have used regular-expressions quite a few times already, and I don't understand what's wrong with my patterns (I'm also surprised I had to specify `./` with `-regex` )?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `regex` type for GNU `find` is `emacs`, which doesn't support intervals. You can specify different regex types, such as `posix-egrep`, which will solve your issue:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex './[0-9]{6}'
```

Comment: Thank you, I also just found this while browsing SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844785/how-to-use-regex-with-find-command. Would you know how to do it using `-name`?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn `-name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`.  Same thing with `ls`: `ls -d [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`.

Comment: @lcd047 Sarcasm.. right? :D

Comment: @Sh3ljohn Nope, serious answer, sadly. :) That's how glob works.  If there's another way to make glob match exactly 6 digits, I'm not aware of it...